# Vue.js set data outside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a component and I would like to set a data item
outside the component.

How would I do this with a directive?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
    bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
    }
});
```

But it's not working:

```js
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
});

Vue.component('test', {
 template: '<p>{{date}}</p>',
  data() {
   return {
      date: ""
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <test v-init:date="'2017-07-20 09:11:42'"></test>
</div>
```

Any Idea how I would get this to work?

--edit--

I don't want to use props for this! I've lots and lots of fields.

Comment: By inspecting `vnode`, it turns out it points to the root vue. That's why it didn't work for you. Check out my answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```js
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    let component = el.__vue__
    component[binding.arg] = binding.value
  }
});

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '<p>{{date}}</p>',
  data() {
    return {
      date: ""
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <test v-init:date="'2017-07-20 09:11:42'"></test>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to a component's data using `$data`.

```js
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
});

Vue.directive('initData', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context.$data[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ciudad: ''
  },
  components: {
    cityInput: {
      data() {
        return {
          ciudad: ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="ciudad" v-init:ciudad="'Madrid'"> {{ciudad}}
  <city-input inline-template>
    <div>
      <input v-model="ciudad" v-init-data:ciudad="'Lisbon'"> {{ciudad}}
    </div>
  </city-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you should be using props for passing the data to your components. As a matter of fact you can use only one variable (either date or initDate), the usage is the same.

```
Vue.component('test', {
  template: '<p>{{date}}</p>',
  props:['initDate'],
  data() {
    return {
            date: ""
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

And then in html you use it like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <test :initDate="2017-07-20 09:11:42"></test>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to put `this.initDate` as the initial value for `date`, tho, right?

Comment: No, I don't want to use ```props``` for this. I have lots of textfields etc.... any Idea how I could fix this?

Comment: @Jenssen Is it always the same value or does it vary? You can set the default value of the property (i.e. you don't have to define anything).

Comment: @Agramer no it's not. I would like to use this with ```Laravel old('date');```

Comment: This is working: https://jsfiddle.net/v5djagta/ but he's not working with components.