# Avoid 2 way databinding on data assignment in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phoenix-framework, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a vue instance:

```
    var vue = new Vue({
      el: '#vue-wrapper',
      data: {
        items: [],
        selectedItem: ''
    })
```

I initialize items with data coming from my phoenix server like this:

```
vue.items = <%= raw(@stories) %>
```

When my page has loaded, i want to select the first item as starting item:

```
vue.selectedItem = vue.items[0]
```

I have an input field in my html that is bind to title property of my object

```
<input type="text" v-model="selectedItem.title"></input>
```

Databinding works fine, problem is that items[0] is updating together with selectedItem, and i don't want it.
What i've tried:

```
var x = vue.items[0];
vue.selectedItem = X;
```

still binding,

```
var x = <%= raw(@stories) %>
vue.items = x[0]
vue.selectedItem = x[0]
```

still binding, and:

```
vue.selectedItem = Object.assign({}, vue.items[0]);
```

and still there's binding between objects.
How can i get 2 way databinding only for selectedItem?

Comment: Yes because it's an editor. So it should be editable

Comment: Try `vue.selectedItem = { ...vue.items[0] };`, or `vue.selectedItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vue.items[0]));` or use something like [lodash#cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep), you need to clone the object, right now you have a reference to the original object.

Comment: Are you looking to [initialize the value from the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215757/392102)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your case in jsfiddle and Object.assign is working very well.

```
var vue = new Vue({
      el: '#vue-wrapper',
      data: {
          items: [{
            title: 'title-item'
          }],
          selectedItem: ''
      }
    })

    vue.selectedItem = Object.assign({}, vue.items[0])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/107302/

Comment: I see. I've already tried it but the binding is still real. I need to check my code to see if i've made another binding somewhere else. Thank you Tomasz